# Find the work done in moving an object along a vector r with a force F

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, vectors, work

$$r=3i+5j-2k$$
$$F=3i-3j+2k$$

What do I do. I know that work = force x distance. However, what vector operation should I do? I was wondering whether I should possible find the unit vector of r and then use the dot product leaving the answer as a multiple of n where n represents the number of units of distance traveled.

Comment: work is a scalar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work done by a force, $W=\vec F.\vec d$
The dot indicates a dot product, and the dot product of two vectors is always a scalar, so there is no need for you to find the unit vector of $\vec r$. (Work is Scalar.)

For two vectors, say, $A=a_xi+a_yj+a_zk$ and $B=b_xi+b_yj+b_zk$, the dot product is, $$A.B=a_xb_x+a_yb_y+a_zb_z$$

You should apply that to the the vectors and leave it at that.

Comment: No need for the unit vector?

Comment: Nope. Work is a scalar, so its directionless. Unit vectors are used when something has a direction.

Comment: I would still get a scalar. I'd find the unit vector then dot that with the force vector

Comment: Yeah but that would only be the work done per unit length. For the total work you need to take the dot product with the complete vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate the scalar product of F and r.

Comment: No need for a unit vector? My thinking behind this was that r is simply a direction vector and the object can move any distance along it.

Comment: You take the length of the vector and divide r by this number and finally take the scalar product of this unit vector $r_0$ and $F$, which will give you the work done per unit space. I thought that you have already given the vector between the start and end point. Ps. The way you describe the solution of the problem is correct.

Comment: This could be a better answer if you included some reasoning as to *why* the scalar product is correct.

Comment: Isn't it the definition of work $W:=\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The work $W$ done by a force $\bf F$ along a path from ${\bf r}_1$ to ${\bf r}_2$ is

$$
W = \int^{{\bf r}_2}_{{\bf r}_1}d{\bf r} \cdot {\bf F}
$$

If $\bf F$ does not depend on $\bf r$ (the $F$ given in your problem is constant), then

$$
W = \left(\int^{{\bf r}_2}_{{\bf r}_1}d{\bf r}\right) \cdot {\bf F} = \left({\bf r}_2 - {\bf r}_1\right) \cdot {\bf F}  = \Delta {\bf r} \cdot {\bf F}
$$

Assuming the $r$ given in your problem is the displacement $\Delta {\bf r}$,

$$
W = \left( 3 {\hat{i}}+5{\hat{j}}-2{\hat{k}} \right) \cdot \left(3{\hat{i}}-3{\hat{j}}+2{\hat{k}}\right)
$$